# How to show block in visible window by clicking another block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please someone help me out on this. Please find the fiddle link below so you will come to know the actual need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.n-stand-b, a.n-stand-a, a.e-stand-b, a.e-stand-a, a.w-stand-b, a.w-stand-a, a.s-stand-b, a.s-stand-a').click(function()      {
    $('[class*="b-"]').removeClass(function(index, className) {
      return (className.match(/(^|\s)b-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
    });
    var stand_class= $(this).attr('class');
    $('div.'+stand_class).hide().prependTo('.container-right-column .container-right').slideDown(1000);
    $('div.'+stand_class).addClass('b-'+stand_class);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oz2k1xav/2/

Right now when I click on the left side stadium anyone of block so accordingly in the right side column it is sliding down at the top of the right container.

And after scrolling down the page I make the left container position fixed and right container scroll-able. And clicking on any stadium block the right container blocks showing on top of container only.

But what I really want that when I scroll down and then click on the left container stadium block, the right container blocks should be shown in visible window not at the top of the right container.

Please someone help me out it's really needy... And please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you have provided prepends the required element to the container, thats why it is always on the top. What you need is to scroll to the required element,

I have added a [jquery plugin(scrollTo)](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) in the below jsfiddle, which does the job

https://jsfiddle.net/oz2k1xav/3/

These are lines modified

```
    //$('div.'+stand_class).hide().prependTo('.container-right-column .container-right').slideDown(1000);

    $.scrollTo($('div.'+stand_class)[0], 1000, {
    offset: -100
    });
```

Comment: Thank You so much Nannakuhtum. This is really what I needed, Thanks for your help.